# Finding a number sequence as an upper bound

Tags: complex-numbers

For the sequence $\frac{1}{n^2 (z-\frac{1}{n})}$ ($n=1,2,....$) on the left half plane, where $z$ is a complex number I would like to find a number sequence that bounds it. I have tried for days and for some reason I cannot find something that works. Thanks!

Comment: Your function is not defined at some points. Even if you avoid those points you cannot bound this by a numerical seqeuence because the function is not bounded in $z$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Sorry I forgot to mention it is defined only on the left half plane so it should work right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $z=x+iy$ with $x <0$. Then $|\frac  1 {n^{2}(z-\frac 1 n)}|=\frac  1 {n^{2}} \frac {|x-\frac 1 n|+|y|} {(x-\frac  1 n)^{2}+y^{2}}$. Split this into two terms. The first term is bounded by  $\frac  1 {n^{2}} \frac 1 {|x-\frac  1 n|} \leq \frac1 n$. The second term is bounded by $\frac  1 {n^{2}} $ if $|y| \geq 1$ and it is bounded by $1$ if $|y| \leq 1$. Hence, the function is bounded by the constant $2$.

A better bound: Use the inequlity $2ab \leq a^{2}+b^{2}$ with $a=|x-\frac 1 n|$ and $ b=|y|$. You will see that the second term is bounded by $\frac 1 {2n}$. Hence, a bettre bound is $\frac 1n +\frac 1 {2n}=\frac 3 {2n}$.

Comment: Thank you very much!